# Spring Cron Expression to run every Tuesday night 9?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cron, spring-scheduled

I am using Spring schedule. I configured the following Cron expression to run my task every Tuesday night at 9pm,

```
"0 0 21 * * TUE"
```

However, I am getting the following exception when am starting the application

> Encountered invalid @Scheduled method 'runSchduler': Cron expression must consist of 6 fields

Is my Spring Cron expression wrong?

Answer (score 3):

> Is my Spring Cron expression configured, to run every Tuesday night at 9
>   wrong?

***Yes :)***

---

But try,

```
0 0 21 ? * TUE
```

Or with the Spring annotation:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 21 * * TUE")
```

---

The following is a really handy website for creating Cron expressions.

http://www.cronmaker.com/ 
Take note: Just remove the last element from the created expression to use it with Spring scheduling.

And a nice way to verify it in Natural Language [here](https://cronexpressiondescriptor.azurewebsites.net/?expression=0%200%2021%20%3F%20*%20TUE&locale=en)

Comment: This website is giving invalid report for valid crons. e.g- 0 0 0/7 * * *

Comment: Extra kudos for "just remove last element" hint. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Cron Expression for Everyday Tuesday Midnight 9 PM

0 0 21 ? * TUE

cleck below cron with zone example

```
  @Component
    public class SpringScheduling {    

        @Scheduled(cron = "0 0 21 ? * TUE",zone="Asia/Calcutta")
        public void trackScheduling() {

              System.out.println("Scheduled task running");

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a field too much?

Just generated this based on your criteria of Tuesdays at 9PM
"0 21 * * 2"